# Visual C# 2015 Serial Port - reading data

Tags: c#, serial-port

I am trying to figure out what is wrong with my code. Serial modem is working. Just testing with ATI command to see the input, but I see nothing. What could be wrong? I am using a thread to read the data from serial buffer.

```
using System;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.Threading;

namespace SerialPortProgram
{
    public class PortChat
    {
        static bool _continue = true;
        static SerialPort port = new SerialPort("COM1", 115200, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);

        public static void Main()
        {
            string message;
            StringComparer stringComparer = StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase;
            Thread readThread = new Thread(Read);

            port.Open();
            port.WriteLine("ATI");
            Console.WriteLine("Type QUIT to exit");
            readThread.Start();
            while (_continue)
            {
                message = Console.ReadLine();

                if (stringComparer.Equals("quit", message))
                {
                    _continue = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    port.WriteLine(message);
                }
            }
            readThread.Join();
            port.Close();
            port.Dispose();
        }
        public static void Read()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("incoming...");
            Console.WriteLine(port.ReadExisting());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: just one word of caution, .nets implementation of serial ports are buggy and you can end up with some weird issues at times, especially if you have USB ports that can disappear at times and come back

Comment: Any suggestions for reliable communication with c#?

Comment: you can buy serial libraries, or what I did, as I have a bunch of experience with it, is write a C++ library for it with native bindings.  Not sure if there is any open source stuff that's any good.

Answer (score 3):

The `SerialPort.ReadExisting()` method doesn't block. So, your code starts a thread, which immediately calls `ReadExisting()`, which immediately returns an empty string, and then that thread exits. It won't ever see the echo from the modem of whatever command you enter; you can't type that fast.

You should not be using an explicit thread here anyway. Instead, handle the `SerialPort.DataReceived` event, and call `ReadExisting()` when the event is raised.

Even better, use the `BaseStream` property to get a `Stream` object, with which you can use the standard `XXXAsync()` methods, which work with `async`/`await` and allow you to write much more readable, easy-to-understand code. Even a console program can benefit from this approach, and if and when you move to a GUI API, it will work even better.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you very much Peter Duniho, with your input I changed my code. Now it works like a charm..!

```
using System;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.Threading;

namespace SerialPortProgram
{
    public class PortChat
    {
        static bool _continue = true;
        static SerialPort port = new SerialPort("COM1", 115200, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);

        public static void Main()
        {
            port.Handshake = Handshake.None;

            string message;
            StringComparer stringComparer = StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase;
            port.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(port_DataReceived);

            port.Open();
            port.WriteLine("ATI");
            Console.WriteLine("Type QUIT to exit");
            while (_continue)
            {
                message = Console.ReadLine();

                if (stringComparer.Equals("quit", message))
                {
                    _continue = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    port.WriteLine(message);
                }
            }
            port.Close();
            port.Dispose();
        }
        private static void port_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            // Show all the incoming data in the port's buffer
            Console.WriteLine(port.ReadExisting());
        }
    }
}
```